# Test 5-card hand for four of a kind

Tags: python, playing-cards

I am trying to test a five card hand to see if it includes four of a kind. Currently I have two functions, `convert(x)` and `draw_n(n)`. They are defined as:

```
def convert(x):
    card = x % 13
    suit = 'SHDC'[x/13]
    return card, suit, str([card, suit])

def draw_n(n):
    from random import sample

    # initialize the list
    cards = []
    # make sure that we have a valid number
    if n > 0 and n <= 52:
        # sample without replacement 
        for x in sample(xrange(0, 52), n):
            # append the converted card to the list
            cards.append(convert(x))
    return cards
```

When `draw_n(n)` is executed with parameter `5` (i.e. draw a 5 card hand), it returns a list with 5 random cards that looks like this:

```
[(8, 'D', '9 of Diamonds'),
 (0, 'H', 'Ace of Hearts'),
 (8, 'H', '9 of Hearts'),
 (10, 'S', 'Jack of Spades'),
 (12, 'C', 'King of Clubs')]
```

The number refers to the number of the card (i.e. 0 = Ace, ..., 12 = King), the letter refers to the suit, and the string is the name of the card.

I will be executing this function multiple times within Python, resulting in multiple 5 card hands. I would like to be able to count the number of hands with four of a kind within the list of 5 card hands, but I have not had any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have tried using split and strip to get the card string (i.e, '9 of Hearts', etc.) by itself, but I have had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you only need a function to tell you if it's a four-of-a-kind. Something like this should do:

```
def is_four_of_a_kind(hand):
    hand = sorted(hand)
    # assumes length >= 5
    return hand[0][0] == hand[3][0] or hand[1][0] == hand[4][0]
```

I recommend **always** having **sorted** hands (by card value), it makes all the process of figuring out what hand you're holding much easier.

Now use it in the resulting number of hands:

```
hands = [draw(5) for _ in xrange(1000)]
four_of_a_kinds = [hand for hand in hands if is_four_of_a_kind(hand)]
four_of_a_kinds_count = len(four_of_a_kinds)
```

Comment: thats a cool way of checking for four fo a kind ... I had to think about it alot ... (which is silly cause its not very confusing)

Comment: I've written a python poker game, this saves a lot of time in many places (holding the hands sorted).

Comment: If you're using the function from within a more general-purpose hand evaluator, don't sort inside the function. Sort the hand once, then allow the functions to assume sorted order (perhaps assert it). That will speed you up considerably.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker that was my intention with "I recommend always having sorted hands (by card value) ...". Obviously you need to sort once.

Answer (score 3):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter
any(v==4 for k,v in Counter(v[0] for v in my_hand).items())
```

is a way to do it ...

Comment: Elegant, and almost but (Py3.x anyway) not quite a way to do it. I don't get the `key` keyword arg to `Counter` (gave errors), and anyway you need the Counter's `items()`. This does do it: `any(v == 4 for v, k in Counter(map(itemgetter(0), my_hand)).items())`

Answer (score 1):

You already have the card's rank in the first element of the triple.

```
rank_count = 13*[0]
for card in hand:
   rank = int(card[0])
   rank_count[rank] += 1

if 4 in rank_count:
   # you have a 4-of-a-kind
```